# multiprocessing lock doesnt prevent race condition when working with json file

Tags: python, json, io, multiprocessing, locking

i have a `json` file that has only one object in it:

`incme.json`:

```json
{
    "value": 0
}
```

I am trying to update it using `multiprocessing` with `ProcessPoolExecutor`, and prevent a race condition using `multiprocessing.Lock`:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import json

def inc(tup):   
    lock, ignoreme = tup
    with lock:
        with open('incme.json', 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
    print (data)
    data['value'] += 1
    with lock:
        with open('incme.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, fp=f, indent=4)
    ignoreme += 1
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = mp.Manager()
    lock = m.Lock()
    
    NUMBER_OF_CPUS = mp.cpu_count()
    # use up to +++ of the cpu`s available 
    USE_UP_TO = 0.5
    
    inc((lock, 1))
    
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=np.uint16(NUMBER_OF_CPUS * USE_UP_TO)) as executor:
        for i in range(100):    
            print('inc:')
            executor.submit(inc, ((lock, 1)))
```

when the code above runs it will make `value` be `44` or something lower than `101`.

when using the lock in this way:

```py
def inc(tup):   
    lock, ignoreme = tup
    with lock:
        with open('incme.json', 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        print (data)
       data['value'] += 1
        with open('incme.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, fp=f, indent=4)
    ignoreme += 1
```

the `value` becomes `101` but now it doesn't work asynchronously.
what could cause this?  does it have something to do with IO related tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lock appears to protect too little. Yes, you read atomically, and you write atomically, but you do *not* do the read-increment-write sequence atomically. There's nothing, e.g., to prevent all 100 processes reading up 0, then each of them adding 1 to 0, and then each of them writing out 1 as the new value.

Instead, try removing the second `with lock:` statement, and indenting the `print()` and increment statements, so that the entire read-increment-write sequence is done atomically.

### Edit

Oops! I see now you already tried that, and already discovered it worked. So I'm just left confused about why you think the original way "should" work. It obviously should not ;-)

Comment: i didn't know about atomic functions and operations. in my real program, the "increment" stage takes about 1 minutes, and the number of processes is about 30. i wanted to make it faster using `multiprocessing`, but when using the lock on the whole function it will not make more than 1 process

Comment: You, in effect, have a pipeline: the input to one process is the output of a prior process, in a long chain. Nothing much can speed that short of getting a faster machine or implementation language. How can parallelism possibly help when one process doesn't even know what input to _start_ with before another process completes? They _inherently_ need to run one at a time them.